# how to loop through angular.forEach and only show results once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, foreach

I want to loop through an array of numbers to see if it matches up with a variable that i want to check for. It's doing the check correctly but it's displaying the result every time it checks it. What i want it to do is....do the check and just spit out the result only once its finished. Is there a way to do that?

```
            var myNumber = 123;
            var sponsorNumber = [345, 234, 525];

            angular.forEach(sponsorNumber, function(value) {
              if (value !== myNumber) {              
                console.log('doesnt match!');
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not print the message inside the loop. You need to maintain a flag that weather it found or not. And then print in the end.

However you don't need foreach here. Just try `indexOf` function.

```
 if (sponsorNumber.indexOf(myNumber) < 0 ) {              
       console.log('doesnt match!');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to do what you actually want? If it returns -1, then you know the array doesn't contain you number. There's no need to reinvent the wheel if there's already a perfect one.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want, you can filter and then loop (less efficient):

```
sponsorNumber.filter(value => value !== myNumber).forEach(function(value) {
    console.log('doesnt match!');
});
```

But it does not make too much sense to me. I think you want something else, like the others commented, using `indexOf`.